# Fatal unable to access 'https://github.com/': The requested URL returned error: 403 - despite following all solutions?

Tags: github, command-line

I deleted my keychain credentials and generated a Personal Access Token on Github.

Once prompted for password in terminal, I entered my PAT (though I do not see the typed input on the screen) - I get an error every time. I went through the published solutions on Stack and nonetheless cannot push my root folders to the new repository on Github.

Is there anything else I can try or another way to upload the full folder with sub folders and file at once? I have GitHub Desktop but cannot see any changes in the history even though I cloned the repository.

My command line path:

```
...-MBP (project-name) % git push -u origin main
Username for 'https://github.com': (my username)
Password for 'https://(my username)@github.com': 
remote: Permission to (my username)/to-do-list.git denied to (my username).
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/(my username)/(project-name).git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got that same error.. what i did to resolve was to go back to setting, then generate another Personal Token Access Token, then below i selected the scopes, or permissions, to grant this token(this step i had skipped previously). Then clicked on Generate Token and the when i used the token again it worked.